# Create a custom widget in blogger.com for 5 input fields?

Tags: html, blogger

I am learning how to create custom blogger templates. I encountered a problem where I needed a custom widget where there would be four to five input fields. I would type the text and show the result in the blog.

When I came to create it, I encountered some problems. I wasn't able to create a custom widget that lets me input text in four or five different fields.

Here is the code that I came up with:

```
<b:section id="custom-widget" name="Custom Widget">
  <b:widget id="Custom-widget1" type="Text">
    <b:widget-settings>
      <b:widget-setting name="content">Custom Widget</b:widget-setting>
    </b:widget-settings>

    <b:includable id="main">
      <b:include name="line1" />
      <b:include name="line2" />      
      <b:include name="line3" />      
      <b:include name="line4" />
      <b:include name="quickedit" />
    </b:includable>

    <b:includable id="line1">
      <p class="line-1">
        <span><data:line1 /></span>
      </p>
    </b:includable>
    <b:includable id="line2">
      <p class="line-2">
        <span><data:line2 /></span>
      </p>
    </b:includable>
    <b:includable id="line3">
      <p class="line-3">
        <span><data:line3 /></span>
      </p>
    </b:includable>
    <b:includable id="line4">
      <p class="line-4">
        <span><data:line4 /></span>
      </p>
    </b:includable>
  </b:widget>
</b:section>
```

As you can see in the code above, I want a simple text field in the widget. But it doesn't work. Blogger just gives me a title field and a content field that I didn't exactly want.

How can I create the text input fields that I want to?